# Retrofit Rx Java Requests

Tags: android, realm, retrofit2, rx-android

I had 2 tables TimeStamps and Infraction, I want to do 
something like that using retrofit with Rx Android :

```
     Request-> I get TimeStamps (if it's changed)
   -> I send new request to get Infractions 
      else I display infractions from database
```

this is what I did using Retrofit, is that correct ??

```
Observable<TimeStamps> callTimeStamp = apiInterface.getTimeStamp();
       TimeStamps stamps = realm.where(TimeStamps.class).findFirst();

       callTimeStamp.flatMap(new Function<TimeStamps, ObservableSource<List<Infraction>>>() {
           @Override
           public ObservableSource<List<Infraction>> apply(TimeStamps timeStamps) throws Exception {

         if(!timeStamps.getInfractionTimeStamps().equalsIgnoreCase( stamps.getInfractionTimeStamps()))
               return apiInterface.getInfractions();
         else
             return null;
           }
       }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
               .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Observer<List<Infraction>>() {
           @Override
           public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onNext(List<Infraction> infractions) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onError(Throwable e) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onComplete() {

           }
       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No

> TimeStamps stamps = realm.where(TimeStamps.class).findFirst();

This obtains `stamps` on the current thread

> if(!timeStamps.getInfractionTimeStamps().equalsIgnoreCase( **stamps.getInfractionTimeStamps()**))

This attempts to access that `stamps` instance on a different thread, so you'll get an IllegalStateException

> return null;

Even if it did work, this line would make RxJava2 throw a NullPointerException

> .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())

This could easily be `Schedulers.io()` instead so that it wouldn't create too many threads (although then of course you should make sure you use `try(Realm realm = ...)` or `finally { realm.close() }`)

> .subscribe(new Observer>() {

This is wrong unless you "properly implement onSubscribe" which is not expected at all, this should be `new DisposableObserver<List<Infraction>>()`.

In which case your Retrofit interface should probably expose `Single<T>`, as singles automatically unsubscribe when done.

---

```
Single<TimeStamps> callTimeStamp = apiInterface.getTimeStamp();

   callTimeStamp.flatMap((timeStamps) -> {
        try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
            TimeStamps stamps = realm.where(TimeStamps.class).findFirst();
            if(!timeStamps.getInfractionTimeStamps().equalsIgnoreCase( stamps.getInfractionTimeStamps()))
                return apiInterface.getInfractions();
            else
                return Single.never();
       }
   }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<List<Infraction>>() {
       @Override
       public void onNext(List<Infraction> infractions) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onError(Throwable e) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onComplete() {

       }
   });
```